# 100 Hz Data From Serial

Tags: c++, windows, serial-port

I have a sensor which uses RS422 to spit out messages over serial. (I think thats the right terminology.)  Anyways, I made my wiring harness, and hooked it up to my rs422 to usb convertor and tada, I got data in hyperterminal.  Good stuff.

Now the sensor has an odd baud rate, 1500kbps.  I am doing this in Windows, so it actually wasn't that hard to set that baud rate.  Initially, at power on, the sensor sends out a 69 byte message every 10hz.  I see this message, the correct bytes are read, and the message is very accurate (it includes a timestamp, which wait for it, increases by 0.1 s every message!)  MOST IMPORTANTLY, I get the message on its boundary, in other words, every read was a new message.

Anyways things are going good so far, so I took the next step, I sent a write command over the serial port, to activate a sensor data message.  This message is 76 bytes large, and is sent out at 100hz.  Success again, more data begins appearing in reads.  However, I am not getting it at 100hz, I get blocks of 3968 bytes.  If I lower my buffer, I get three very very very quick reads of 1024, then immediately a read of 896.  (3968 bytes again).  (Note that I am now receiving two messages, one at 10 hz with size 69, and one at 100hz with size 76, note that no combination of the two messages evenly divides 3968.)

My question is, somewhere something is buffering my 100hz messages, and I am not getting them as they're being received.  I would like to change that but I do not know what I'm looking for.  I don't need that 100hz message on its boundary, I just don't want it at 2 Hz.  I would be happy with 30hz or even 20hz.

---

**Below I include my Serial Port Set up code:**

Port Open

```
 serial_port_ = CreateFile(L"COM6", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
```

CommState and Timeouts

```
 COMMTIMEOUTS comm_timeouts;
 ZeroMemory(&comm_timeouts, sizeof(COMMTIMEOUTS));
 //comm_timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = MAXDWORD; //Instant Read, still get 3968 chunks
 comm_timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 1; //1ms timeout
 comm_timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 1000; //Derp?
 comm_timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 5000; //Derp.
 SetCommTimeouts(serial_port_, &comm_timeouts);

 DCB dcb_configuration;
 ZeroMemory(&dcb_configuration, sizeof(DCB));
 dcb_configuration.DCBlength = sizeof(dcb_configuration);
 dcb_configuration.BaudRate = 1500000;
 dcb_configuration.ByteSize = 8;
 dcb_configuration.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
 dcb_configuration.Parity = ODDPARITY;
 if(!SetCommState(serial_port_, &dcb_configuration))
```

My Read

```
 if(!ReadFile(serial_port_, read_buffer_, 1024, &bytes_read, NULL))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suspect your serial->usb convertor to do the buffering. Since the usb is packet based, it needs to do some buffering. In rate 10Hz, there are probably big enough delays, to flush buffer after every message. But at 100Hz the messages are coming so far, that it is flushing buffer by some other logic.

Does that make sense?

Comment: It does, and it is what I think as well.  However, I am new to serial port programming so I don't want to make that assumption yet.  If it is true though, how do I get around it?  Is there a way to set the system buffer for the serial port?  The api calls probably affect the serial convertors driver, is there a windows api call to set the comm buffer?  My point is, we know the converter is capable of 10HZ, lets at least get that.  Not 2 HZ

Comment: I looked at this once (similar application). A good explanation of what the USB converter does can be found in http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN232B-04_DataLatencyFlow.pdf section 3.1. The document is for the FTDI FT232 but I assume others work similar. (There are other useful application notes ) If you are using a FT232 device you can set this latency timer. I believe it can also be done in Windows but I never tried it. For Linux you can use http://www.intra2net.com/en/developer/libftdi/documentation/group__libftdi.html#ga3e0227b0c7aa859d2d2afb5ffa4c8466

Comment: Found it for windows for the FT232 devices, it is in AN_107 Advanced driver options: http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN_107_AdvancedDriverOptions_AN_000073.pdf

Comment: I think mine is actually FTDI chip, I don't know what kind though.  I couldn't figure it out.  It's model number is UTS-M14, a 4 port usb convertor.  The only one I could find that supported > 1500 kbps

Comment: Hey so my driver let me change those from Device Manager, I adjusted the Timeout form 16 ms to 8ms, works like a charm now.  Thanks for the documentation rve, please make an answer so I may accept it for others!